# Locker room question generalized to n people - repeating error

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Program11 {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Number of lockers:");
    int number = input.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print("Show stages [y/n]?");
    String show = input.next();
    if(show.equals("y")) 
    {
      for (char[] lockers : getStages(number)) 
      { 
        for (char c : lockers) 
        { 
          System.out.print("" + c); 
        } 
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
  }

  public static char[][] getStages(int n){      
    char[] lockers = new char[n];
    char[][] arrayLockers = new char[n][];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      lockers[i] = 'O';
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<1;i++){
      arrayLockers[i] = lockers;
    }
    for(int i = 2; i<=n; i++){
      for(int z = 1; z<n; z++){
        for (int w = i-1; w <= n; w += i){
          lockers[w] = 'X'; 
        }
        arrayLockers[z] = lockers;
      }

    }
    return arrayLockers;
  }
}
```

The output is for n = 10:

```
> run Program11
Number of lockers: 10
Show stages [y/n]? y
OXXXXXXXXX
OXXXXXXXXX
OXXXXXXXXX
OXXXXXXXXX
OXXXXXXXXX
OXXXXXXXXX
OXXXXXXXXX
OXXXXXXXXX
OXXXXXXXXX
OXXXXXXXXX
>
```

The locker room problem goes as follows:
There are n students and n lockers. The first student opens all the lockers. The second student closes lockers 2,4,6,8,.... the third student closes lockers 3,6,9,12,... This patterns repeats itself until all n students have gone.

**My task:**

I am supposed to show the lockers at each stage for a given n. 'X' represents closed and 'O' represents open. I am supposed to use arrays only. Clearly this is repeating the same array over and over again which is incorrect. I used the method getStages to return a multi-dimensional array "arrayLockers" to store each stage. 
Could anyone tell me where I have gone wrong?

**Expected output is:**

```
OOOOOOOOOO   
OXOXOXOXOX   
OXXXOXXXXX   
OXXXOXXXXX  
OXXXXXXXXX  
OXXXXXXXXX  
OXXXXXXXXX    
OXXXXXXXXX   
OXXXXXXXXX    
OXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: `arrayLockers[z] = lockers;` Are you assigning one array to another here? Instead, use `System.arraycopy()` function.

Comment: Correct, this is where i make my multi-dimensional array.

Comment: What is your expected output? I have done a code here, if that's what you want. [link](https://ideone.com/mSSDeu)

Comment: See the link, if you are getting the desired output. And please post expected output in your question itself.

Comment: that is not the expected output but thank you for trying.

Comment: Then what is the expected outcome? Is there a pattern/algorithm or should it be random which ones are opened?

Comment: Please see the edit I just made explaining the locker room problem. It is not random

Comment: @theboy88, See this [link](https://ideone.com/mSSDeu). I think this is what you expected.

Comment: Thanks @kiner_shah, that is correct. I will compare my code to see where my logic went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some problems with your code. Firstly, you were not allocating memory to `arrayLockers` before copying. Secondly, you were complicating the logic by using three `for` loops (nested). It could be done with just two nested loops. Also, you were using array assignment which I am not sure whether it works; so I changed it with `System.arraycopy()` which I use often (or you can do it manually using a `for` loop).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Program11 {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Number of lockers:\n");
    int number = input.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print("Show stages [y/n]?\n");
    String show = input.next();
    if(show.equals("y")) 
    {
      for (char[] lockers : getStages(number)) 
      { 
        for (char c : lockers) 
        { 
          System.out.print("" + c); 
        } 
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
  }

  public static char[][] getStages(int n){      
    char[] lockers = new char[n];
    char[][] arrayLockers = new char[n][];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      lockers[i] = 'O';
    }
    arrayLockers[0] = new char[lockers.length];
    System.arraycopy(lockers, 0, arrayLockers[0], 0, lockers.length);
    int cnt = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j += cnt) {
            lockers[j] = 'X';
        }
        arrayLockers[i] = new char[lockers.length];
        System.arraycopy(lockers, 0, arrayLockers[i], 0, lockers.length);
        cnt++;
    }
    return arrayLockers;
  }
}
```